# Generating SOAP Java classes from XSD using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, soap, xsd, wsdl

I need to generate a SOAP web service (client and server), and I only have an XSD file, no WSDL. I've only written a web service from WSDL before. I'm also new to IntelliJ IDEA, and I found that [it has a tool to generate the code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-java-code-from-xml-schema-using-xmlbeans-dialog.html).

However, I don't see where that dialog should appear, when opening the .xsd file. I have the Java EE:WebServices plugin installed and enabled, but I don't see the Web plugin on the list, apart from that I have a "Web" box on the tools tab which I can open.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2018.1.

Is it possible to generate the WebService Java classes in this way? What am I doing wrong?

Otherwise, I had the following ideas:

1. Use xjc (new to this, too)
2. Write a "fake" wsdl using the xsd, then generating from wsimport
3. Writing the code myself using an xml parser

I need some quick and dirty solution. Any recommendations?

Comment: Make sure you have **Java EE: Web Services (JAX-WS)** plugin enabled. Then you should see the Settings(Preferences) | Tools | Web Services settings page. If xsd file has schema declaration the option should be available in menu: Tools | XmlBeans | Generate Java Code From XML Schema Using XmlBeans.

Comment: @Andrey I had it enabled, but your comment was helpful in opening the Web Services settings. I entered the XmlBeans plugin location here, after installing it manually (I don't know why it isn't included?). But I still got an "Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaCompiler", even after adding the xbean.jar into the classpath. I solved it by copying said .jar to the .IntelliJIdea2018.1\plugins directory under the Users folder in Windows.